# ¿Latinoamérica: por qué se usa "latino" con un sustantivo feminino?

Tags: etimología, género, concordancia-gramatical, compuestos

El sustantivo "América" es feminino y "latino" es adjetivo. Así, ya que los adjetivos han de concordar con los sustantivos que modifican, ¿por qué se usa "latino" en lugar "latina" en el sustantivo compuesto "Latinoamérica"? ¿No debe ser "Latinaamérica"?

The noun "América" is feminine and "latino" is an adjective. So, given that adjectives have to agree with the nouns they modify, why is "latino" used instead of "latina" in the compound noun "Latinoamérica? Shouldn't it be "Latinaamérica"?

Comment: Me atrevería a decir que la escritura se debe solamente por un tema fonético, por eso no más quedó como *latinoamérica.*

Answer (score 3):

Lo normal es que la primera palabra del par que forma la palabra compuesta, si tiene flexión de género (o sea si es sustantivo o adjetivo) se fije en el masculino. Los siguientes ejemplos demuestran que es sistemático y que no tiene que ver con que suena mal decir *Latinaamérica*.

> Una reacción **fisicoquímica**.
>
> Una amiga **sordomuda**.
>
> Una convención **chileno-argentina**.
>
> La **decimoprimera** edición.
>
> Una ministra **todopoderosa**.

Incluso en este caso que casi no tiene lógica:

> La **drogodependencia**.

La única excepción que se me viene a la cabeza es **medianoche**.

Comment: El problema es que, en palabras compuestas de sustantivo y adjetivo, según todo lo que he visto, se suele concordar el adjetivo con el sustantivo, por ejemplo "altavoz", "purasangre", "malasombra", y "medialuna". Como se puede ver, estas palabras se componen de un adjetivo antes un sustantivo, como "Latinoamérica" - hay más ejemplos pero no son muy comunes. Los ejemplos a lo contrario que he encontrado solo usan "mal-" o "buen-". Hay muchos ejemplos del forma sustantivo-adjetivo también en los que el adjetivo concuerda con el sustantivo.

Comment: Creo de modo muy personal, que es un tema netamente fonético, que a lo largo del tiempo se ha ido modificando las palabras y han llegado a tal construcción.

Answer (score 1):

Estoy de acuerdo con @Ustanak. El uso de doble vocal, tal como sería el caso si fuese escrita "latinaamérica" es evitado por lo general por convenciones comunes.

Abundan ejemplos en el castellano, más comúnmente observados en el uso del artículo definitivo "el" delante de sustantivos que comienzan con el sonido "a".

Observe "el agua", "el águila".

Comment: [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=am%C3%A9rica) no está de acuerdo con la idea, aunque me cae la cuenta q podría haber sido también.

Comment: Si eso fuera la razón, pensaría que sería "Latinamérica" o "Latiniamérica" - el perder el vocal y el hacerlo una "i" me parecen lo más común adentro de palabras compuestas, por ejemplo "aguardiente" o "santiamén".

Answer (score 0):

In the word "latinoamérica", "latino"is word component and not an adjective.  Agreement does not apply.

Comment: Do you have any reference? What do you mean by "word component"? Could you elaborate?

Comment: I just mean part of a word.  That makes it not an adjective.  No references.

Comment: Se debe a que el español es una lengua _indoeuropea_. Mentira, no es esa la razón, pero ¿no es curioso que la India es femenino pero se dice indoeuropea? Parece que los nombres de lugares en sustantivos compuestos no cuentan como adjetivos.

Comment: @Yay the term in Spanish is *elemento composicional*. These do not agree in gender as they are fixed forms. Note for instance, the difference between the entry for *hispano, -a* and *hispano-* in the DRAE. Though *latino-* doesn't have its own entry, it's clear it's being used the same way.

Comment: @SantiagoTórtora [Esta entrada de la RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=cvqPbpreSD6esL3ahc) explica que el primer elemento de un adjetivo compuesto permanece invariable y el segundo concuerda en género y número con el sustantivo. Explicaría el caso de "indoreuropea" pero no el de "Latinoamérica", que no es adjetivo sino sustantivo.

Comment: Looking at the [wikipedia article](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/History_of_Latin_America#/Origin_of_the_term_and_definition) — there is the section on etymology. It was interesting to find that the term was a political invention, and that it was actually coined by Napolean. "Latin" refers to the idea that there was a "latin race" by then at that part of the world, their own distinct peoples. The Latin in "Latin America" doens't refer to an "america of _the_ Latinos", it inflects the same sense of being latin that it does when applied _to those people_. In other words, it is an adjective.

Comment: @Yay - I agree, this latest response of yours is the answer. You should submit it separately. The specific citation from that guide would be " hispanorromana, [ciudadano] francocanadiense, [dialecto] navarroaragonés...[relaciones] germano-soviéticas, [frontera] chileno-argentina, [cumbre] luso-española...el primer elemento permanece invariable, mientras que el segundo concuerda en género y número con el sustantivo"

Comment: The thing that confuses me is that that pattern is great for two adjectives, but with adjective-noun combinations there are plenty of counter examples like "altavoz", "purasangre", "malasombra", "medialuna", and "medianoche" that contradict that theory.

Comment: fireee: Indeed. My hypothesis is that the original term was *América Latina*, then the demonym *latinoamericano* was created in accordance with the rules (the first element is invariable, etc), and then the term *Latinoamérica* was coined through [back-formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_back-formations). I've been searching for a source supporting the fact both América Latina and latinoaméricano are previous to Latinoamérica but haven't found any authoritative source, so, again, it's just a hypothesis.

Comment: OK, I stand corrected in one regard.  In words like "purasangre", agreement does apply.  So it looks like it applies sometime, but not always.  And, it's important to realize that most evolutions in language are not done by people consciously following rules, but rather speaking in a way that seems "natural" to them.  Linguists come along later, and discover the rules through analysis.

Comment: I looked up Latinoamérica in my copy of the Pequeño Larousse Ilustrado (ink on paper, last century) where I found it in the third section where proper names and place names are defined.  It gave the usual definition, but nothing about the etymology.

Comment: @Yay Indeed that seems the most probable reason to me. I should note, however, that I have found a few examples in which the adjective doesn't agree but they are formed with buen- or mal- (like "malnutrición").