# ¿Tienen nombre en español las partes de una canción que se repiten pero no son el estribillo?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, música

> NOTA: He modificado sustancialmente esta pregunta tras consultar en Music Theory [la diferencia entre "chorus" y "refrain"](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/69616/49491).

---

Leyendo sobre teoría de la música y estructura de canciones, veo que en inglés usan dos palabras para referirse a lo que nosotros conocemos como *[estribillo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GzV3CkN)*: *chorus* y *refrain*. No parece haber un consenso acerca de cuál es la diferencia entre ambas, aunque algunos usan *chorus* como el estribillo propiamente dicho, y *refrain* cuando no hay un estribillo como tal pero si alguna parte de la canción que se repite a veces.

En [la pregunta que hice en Music Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/69616/49491) puse como ejemplos los siguientes:

- *Chorus*: la parte del "We all live in a yellow submarine" en la canción de los Beatles.
- *Refrain*: el hecho de que todos los párrafos en *The sound of silence* acaben repitiendo el título de la canción de la misma forma.

Una de las respuestas parece concordar conmigo diciendo que este razonamiento parece válido. Pero con independencia de cuál sea la distinción que se haga en inglés, ¿se hace en teoría de la música en español esta distinción? Si es así, ¿cuál es el término que se podría usar, en su caso, para la figura musical usada en *The sound of silence* de repetir un verso fijo cada X tiempo, sin que llegue a ser un estribillo?

---

Ejemplo para observar la diferencia entre ambos conceptos: *So far away* de Dire Straits.

```
Here I am again in this mean old town
And you're so far away from me               <-- frase que se repite
And where are you when the sun goes down
You're so far away from me                   <-- frase que se repite

    You're so far away from me               |
    So far I just can't see                  | estribillo
    You're so far away from me               |
    You're so far away from me, all right    |

I'm tired of being in love and being all alone
When you're so far away from me              <-- frase que se repite
I'm tired of making out on the telephone
'Cause you're so far away from me            <-- frase que se repite

    You're so far away from me               |
    So far I just can't see                  | estribillo
    You're so far away from me               |
    You're so far away from me, all right    |

And I get so tired when I have to explain
When you're so far away from me              <-- frase que se repite
See you've been in the sun and I've been in the rain
And you're so far away from me               <-- frase que se repite

    You're so far away from me               |
    So far I just can't see                  | estribillo
    You're so far away from me               |
    You're so far away from me               |
```

Comment: Me pregunto si la cola que se describe aquí viene siendo parecida al "refrain." (corregí una falta de dedo en el comentario original)

Comment: Creí que dejé un comentario en Music SE pero ahora no lo encuentro.  Para más seguro lo dejo aquí.  La respuesta que recibiste de Areel me parece muy bien; si la de Kevin te confunde, no te preocupes, se contradice un poco y pienso que sería mejor que te enfocaras en la respuesta de Areel. Por otra parte toma en cuenta que la teoría de la música principalmente *describe* el milagro de la composición.  Es decir, su principal utilidad consiste en describir, más que prescribir.

Comment: @aparente001 sí, de hecho marqué su respuesta como aceptada. Me sorprendió la aceptación que ha tenido la pregunta en el sitio. Ahora entiendo que la diferencia entre ambos términos es sutil o inexistente, y por eso modifiqué esta pregunta.

Comment: "Inexistente"?  Eso no es lo que yo capté del asunto.  Lo que capté es que "refrán" es un término un tanto resbaloso incluso en inglés; y que el refrán es un fragmento repetido, mientras que el coro es una sección repetida. Es decir, el coro es algo más grande que el refrán.  También: que muchas canciones no tienen refrán como tal; pero que la gran mayoría de canciones sí tienen coro.

Comment: @aparente001 pero pone como ejemplo una canción con un estribillo al que se refieren como "refrain". A lo mejor me he liado...

Comment: De Areel entendí que la manera de usar el término "refrain" depende del género de música que estás describiendo o analizando.  Al final, con lo que dice del hipopótamo, creo que confirma la distinción que tú marcaste aquí con el ejemplo, "So far away." El hecho de que las diversas fuentes en inglés no estén totalmente de acuerdo en cómo utilizar "refrain" no cambia eso.  Pero en fin, si uno quiere usar el término "refrain" o "refrán," valdría la pena aclarar la definición que tienes en mente, al comienzo del escrito o de la conversación.  Eso es lo que capté.

Comment: Creo que es parecido a un comentario que encontré ahora en https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16077/latinoamérica-por-qué-se-usa-latino-con-un-sustantivo-feminino?#comment20077_16078: "it's important to realize that most evolutions in language are not done by people consciously following rules, but rather speaking in a way that seems "natural" to them. Linguists come along later, and discover the rules through analysis."  Se puede poner "Music theorists" en lugar de "Linguists".  Walter Mitty expresó bien la idea que estaba tratando de expresar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En español, cuando hablamos de canciones, a la *estrofa* que se repite con igual letra y música tras cada verso se la conoce como [**estribillo**](https://www.escribircanciones.com.ar/icomo-componer-musica/62-estructura-de-una-cancion.html) o, especialmente en Latinoamérica, "[**coro**](https://blog.landr.com/es/como-componer-una-cancion/)" (aunque esa acepción aún no esté en el DLE). Esto es lo que en inglés sería el ***chorus***.

El ***refrain***, por etimología debería ser '[refrán](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VesRhX7)' en español, pero nadie lo llama así.
[Hay quien usa el término "**gancho**"](https://www.escribircanciones.com.ar/indice-de-figuras/429-gancho.html) con un significado bastante similar:

> Consiste en una palabra, frase o sonido, que se repite a lo largo de la canción. Su función es llamar la atención y lograr captar la atención del oyente, generalmente el gancho se asocia con un motivo musical. Es de carácter breve y aparece repetido en diferentes niveles de la obra.

Aunque lo normal en inglés es llamar al gancho "hook", no "refrain", así que no estoy seguro de si son equivalentes.

A falta de un término específico, algunos que podrías usar son:

> [motivo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PwDYZFz#B6vq1Rf)
>
> 3. m. En arte, rasgo característico que se repite en una obra o en un conjunto de ellas.
>
> [muletilla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Q35TpeW#B9f5NMz)
>
> 2. f. Voz o frase que se repite mucho por hábito.

También te podrían valer [tema](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZOke7eQ) o [lema](http://dle.rae.es/?id=N6HonBK).

Comment: Buena respuesta. El concepto de "tema" lo había sopesado yo pero no he querido ponerlo para ver si a alguien más se le ocurría, lo que pasa es que yo entiendo que suele usarse más en música clásica o en bandas sonoras. He añadido a la pregunta un ejemplo más elaborado, a ver si se te ocurre algo más. En [este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y5LLHZf9ebU) se explican muy bien los conceptos de "motivo" y "tema" aplicados a bandas sonoras.

Answer (score 4):

No creo que exista el *refrain* como tal dentro de la teoría musical en el español, ya que tanto estribillo como coro son considerados lo mismo, ya sea como  un verso o estrofa que se repiten y unen el resto de la canción.

A veces los conceptos de "estribillo" y "Coro" pueden intercambiarse, pudiendo llamar estribillo al coro, aunque esto no siempre aplica a la inversa

La idea principal es por que el estribillo es "**generalmente**" un solo verso (aunque este puede carecer de rima), mientras que el coro **"debe"** ser una estrofa completa.

Ejemplo de estribillo: ["En algún lugar" (Duncan Dhu)](https://youtu.be/Myn7ghLQltI?t=44s)

"en algún lugar de un gran país"
letra ...

"en algún lugar de un gran país"
más letra ...

Comment: Creo que hay una contradicción en el primer párrafo aunque está creo es la respuesta correcta. El ejemplo de estribillo que das es muy claro y corresponde exactamente a la definición que da @Charlie para _refrain_ **"a repeated line or musical phrase that ties a song together.**. El _chorus_ entonces equivale al coro siendo una estrofa completa con rima y demás. +1

Comment: ampliare un poco la respuesta para aclarar esa contradiccion

Comment: No termino de ver eso que dices. Yo siempre he visto "coro" en sentido literal, es decir, en la parte donde se añaden voces secundarias de fondo. Nunca he visto "coro" en el sentido de "estribillo", y creo que podría llevar a confusión.

Comment: Estoy con @FGSUZ, no veo ninguna definición de "coro" ni en el DLE ni en el de americanismos que indique que "coro" tenga el significado de "estribillo". Puede que "coro" sea un falso amigo de "chorus", que debería traducirse como "estribillo", y por tanto el término "refrain" queda huérfano de traducción, que es lo que busco.

Comment: @Charlie y walen. Tienen razón en todo lo que dicen, pero, comprendí bastante bien las respuesta de Mike y la siento correcta, probablemente porque hay diferencias regionales que no han sido recopiladas por el DLE. En el habla corriente chilena la estrofa repetida se conoce como "coro" o "estribillo". La frasecita pegajosa es un "estribillo".

Comment: es correcto decir que coro empeso a utilizarse para referirse a "chorus", pero la palabra correcta en español es "estribillo"

Comment: He modificado la pregunta para que quede así más claro lo que busco. Lamento haber creado confusión con la redacción inicial, después de preguntar en Music Theory parece que he podido aclararme un poco y así formular la pregunta mejor. Si lo crees necesario, cambia la respuesta para que se adapte mejor a la pregunta. Mis disculpas nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré un libro publicado en español que habla del refrán de una canción: https://books.google.com/books?isbn=9561412217

> *Chilena o cueca tradicional* - página 178: La tonada cada seis versos o dos coplas lleva “jarcha” en el coro, y lo cual nosotros llamamos refrán o estribillo. Los dos primeros versos de la copla, con los que se desarrolla la música de 16 metros, son los que durante el canto se repiten con la segunda parte de la melodía.

Sin embargo parece que es muy poco común utilizar *refrán* así en español.  Por lo tanto, si estás describiendo una canción, y se te antoja hacer una distinción entre *coro* (o *estribillo*) y *refrán*, recomiendo que expliques lo que quieres decir con *refrán*, por ejemplo:

> [bla bla bla] el refrán (pequeño segmento que aparece varias veces en la cancion).

Lo que entendí de Wikipedia y Music SE es que el refrán es un fragmento repetido, mientras que el coro es una sección repetida.  Es decir, el coro es algo más grande que el refrán.  También capté que muchas canciones no tienen refrán como tal; pero que la gran mayoría de canciones sí tienen coro.

Por otra parte también capté que "refrán" es un término un tanto resbaloso incluso en inglés.

Comment: Eso parece una traducción literal del inglés, no creo que se use *refrán* con ese significado en español